# phpunit whitelist single file

Tags: php, phpunit

I am trying to specify a white list of file for phpunit coverage with the following config file

```
<filter>
    <whitelist addUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
        <directory suffix=".php">/root/qa/cs/shared/classes</directory>
        <file>/root/qa/cs/classes/p3array.php</file>
        <exclude>
            <directory suffix=".php">/root/qa/cs/shared/classes/_unittest</directory>
        </exclude>
    </whitelist>
</filter>
<logging>
    <log type="coverage-html" target="./results"/>
</logging>

<testsuites>
    <testsuite name="Shared">
        <directory suffix="Test.php">./shared/</directory>
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

But the generated report contains results for all the classes in folder, whereas I thought I was specifying to only produce results for the file p3array.php

How con I just get the results for a single single file

Any help appreciated

PHPUnit 4.8.27
PHP 5.3.3

Comment: You specify a single file and a whole directory for coverage ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this has to do with the versions of phpunit
I believe that the whitelist is only used from version 5 onwards
I have deleted the filter from my config file and added a @covers doc tag to the tests and now get what I exepected